# The name "Tables","m_BarcodeText" and "BarcodeValue" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Hello Everyone!
Help me Please
I get this error messages:
 The name "Tables" does not exist in the current context
 The name "m_BarcodeText" does not exist in the current context
 The name "BarcodeValue" does not exist in the current context
Where is my mistakes? How can I fix this mistakes?Thank's for answers!

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace Barcode
{
    public partial class userControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public userControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

#region "Declarations"
    private struct Ean13Tables
    {
        public string TableA;
        public string TableB;
        public string TableC;
    }
    private Ean13Tables[] Tables = new Ean13Tables[10];
    private StringBuilder BarcodeValue;
    #endregion

    private string m_BarcodeText;
    //[ComponentModel.Category("Barcode"), ComponentModel.Description("The Barcode Value" + Constants.vbCrLf + "must consist of 12 digit"), 
        //ComponentModel.RefreshProperties(ComponentModel.RefreshProperties.All)]
    public string Value
    {
        //Overrides
        get { return m_BarcodeText; }
        set
        {
            if ((value.Length == 12) & (Information.IsNumeric(value)))
            {
                m_BarcodeText = value;
                this.Refresh();
            }
            else if ((value.Length != 12))
            {
                InitBarcode();
                throw new Exception("EAN13 Barcode Must Consist Of 12 Digits");
            }
            else if (!(Information.IsNumeric(value)))
            {
                InitBarcode();
                throw new Exception("EAN13 Barcode Must Consist Of Digits Only");

            }
        }
    }



    private bool m_ShowBarcodeText;
    //[ComponentModel.Category("Barcode"), ComponentModel.Description("show Barcode value under barcode bars"), 
        //ComponentModel.RefreshProperties(ComponentModel.RefreshProperties.All)]
    public bool ShowBarcodeText
    {
        //Overrides
        get { return m_ShowBarcodeText; }
        set
        {
            m_ShowBarcodeText = value;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private byte m_CheckSum;
    //[ComponentModel.Category("Barcode"), 
        //ComponentModel.Description("Check Digit Value")]
    public byte CheckSum
    {
        get
        {
            CalculateCheckSum();
            return m_CheckSum;
        }
    }


    public void New() {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        InitBarcode();
        InitEAN13Tables();
        M_BarWidth = 0.33;
        // mm
        this.Font = new Font("Arial", 18);
        // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    }

    #region "Init Procedures"

    private void InitBarcode()
    {
        m_BarcodeText = "000000000000";
    }

    public void InitEAN13Tables()
    {
        //          Zero
        Tables(0).TableA = "0001101";
        Tables(0).TableB = "0100111";
        Tables(0).TableC = "1110010";
        //          One
        Tables(1).TableA = "0011001";
        Tables(1).TableB = "0110011";
        Tables(1).TableC = "1100110";
        //          Two
        Tables(2).TableA = "0010011";
        Tables(2).TableB = "0011011";
        Tables(2).TableC = "1101100";
        //          Three
        Tables(3).TableA = "0111101";
        Tables(3).TableB = "0100001";
        Tables(3).TableC = "1000010";
        //          Four
        Tables(4).TableA = "0100011";
        Tables(4).TableB = "0011101";
        Tables(4).TableC = "1011100";
        //          Five
        Tables(5).TableA = "0110001";
        Tables(5).TableB = "0111001";
        Tables(5).TableC = "1001110";
        //          Six
        Tables(6).TableA = "0101111";
        Tables(6).TableB = "0000101";
        Tables(6).TableC = "1010000";
        //          Seven
        Tables(7).TableA = "0111011";
        Tables(7).TableB = "0010001";
        Tables(7).TableC = "1000100";
        //          Eight
        Tables(8).TableA = "0110111";
        Tables(8).TableB = "0001001";
        Tables(8).TableC = "1001000";
        //          Nine
        Tables(9).TableA = "0001011";
        Tables(9).TableB = "0010111";
        Tables(9).TableC = "1110100";

    }
    #endregion

    private bool CalculateCheckSum()
    {
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        int j = 11;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    X += Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(j));
                }
                else
                {
                    X += Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(j));
                }
                j -= 1;
            }

            int Z = X + (3 * Y);
          double m_CheckSum = ((10 - (Z % 10)) % 10);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }


    private bool CalculateValue()
    {
        // Clear any previous Value
        BarcodeValue = new StringBuilder(95);
        try
        {
            // Add The Start Mark
            BarcodeValue.Append(StartMark);
            switch (m_BarcodeText(0))
            {
                case "0":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                    }

                    break;
                case "1":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 2) | (i == 4))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "2":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 2) | (i == 5))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "3":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 2) | (i == 6))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "4":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 3) | (i == 4))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "5":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 4) | (i == 5))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "6":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 5) | (i == 6))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "7":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 3) | (i == 5))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "8":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 3) | (i == 6))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "9":
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
                    {
                        if ((i == 1) | (i == 4) | (i == 6))
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableA);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableB);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
            // Add The Splitting Mark
            BarcodeValue.Append(SplittingMark);
            for (int i = 7; i <= (m_BarcodeText.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(Conversion.Val(m_BarcodeText(i))).TableC);
            }
            // Add Checksum
            BarcodeValue.Append(Tables(CheckSum).TableC);
            // Add The End Mark
            BarcodeValue.Append(EndMark);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }



    private void DrawBarcodeText(PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        dynamic drawFont = this.Font;
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        double x = 3.61;
        float y = (30 + (5 * 0.33f));
        drawString += CheckSum.ToString();
        x -= 1.2f;
. 
        SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
        stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(drawString, drawFont);

        RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, y, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;


        e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect, drawFormat);
    }


    private void EAN13Barcode_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateValue(); 
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
        float s = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 94; i++)
        {
            if (BarcodeValue(i) == "1")
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 45:
                    case 46:
                    case 47:
                    case 48:
                    case 49:
                    case 92:
                    case 93:
                    case 94:
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), s + 0.11f, 10, 0.5f, (20 + (5 * 0.33f)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), s + 0.11f, 10, 0.5f, 20);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (BarcodeValue(i) == "0")
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 45:
                    case 46:
                    case 47:
                    case 48:
                    case 49:
                    case 92:
                    case 93:
                    case 94:
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), s + 0.11f, 10, 0.5f, (20 + (5 * 0.33f)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), s + 0.11f, 10, 0.5f, 20);
                        break;
                }
            }

            s += 0.5f;
        }

        //If ShowBarcodeText = True Then
        DrawBarcodeText(e);
        //End If

    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention the line which is throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rearrange variable declaration  in proper way .It  must be  a declaration problem**

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are mistakes otherwise the compiler wouldn't say so.